# Are ERP questions off-topic on SO?

Tags: support, reopen-closed, on-hold

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564399/how-to-set-up-a-multi-organization-structure-with-hierarchies-in-oracle-erp) earlier today in SO. It was about Oracle ERP. Those who know about ERP knows that it is about forms, reports and setups. I noticed the [erp](/questions/tagged/erp) tag in SO and thought that questions about ERP can be asked in SO because I don't really know any other Stack Exchange site to ask it in. But now some people have come and put the question on hold as being off-topic. But ERP questions don't have much code in it except for the occasional PL/SQL questions on how to manipulate ERP.

So are ERP questions off-topic to SO? Or is it something about [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564399/how-to-set-up-a-multi-organization-structure-with-hierarchies-in-oracle-erp)? Because I checked some other ERP questions and they are similar to mine:
[example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288051/integration-between-2-modules-in-erp-system) and [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287596/what-is-the-most-easy-to-learn-open-source-erp-system).

The thing is that you don't get many answers in the case of ERP questions. If so, on which Stack Exchange site does this question belong?

Comment: Your basically asking us to point you at external resources. Such questions are indeed not appropriate for Stack Overflow. That is not limited to ERP questions.

Comment: @Bart Ya, but that is if people finds it difficult to explain it on SO, which i know they will, in this case!

Comment: Your first example isn't really similar to your question, it's a programming question. Your second example is off topic, and I suspect it'll be closed very soon, now that you've brought attention to it.

Comment: Say what @prince...I have no clue what you're trying to say in that comment.

Comment: @Bart i have edited my question a bit now. What i meant was that my question will probably have an answer which is pretty hard to explain. But now i have removed the line asking for resources. Is that ok?

Comment: @Yannis Actually no. In example1, he needs to integrate two modules. I need to "secure access to data so that users can access only the
information that is relevant to them" which is doing just the opposite. But both are related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an ERP guy, but it seems like you are asking about how to setup and ERP system.

> secure access to data so that users can access only the information
>   that is relevant to them

It seems like you can do that with a mouse and point and clicking at buttons.

Stack Overflow is for *programming*-related questions - I think a good rule of thumb is if it involves typing words and letters most non programmers simply refer to as "code" it may fit.

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code

Also a good question usually shows what they have already tried and what are they stuck with specifically. I don't think you *can* do this with this question.

It doesn't mean it's bad; it just means it doesn't fit.

Keep in mind Stack Exchange is community moderated so maybe some other moderator wouldn't have put the question on hold, but I doubt it.

Comment: ya, and i am willing to accept that but my question was that if it doesnt fit here, where does it fit? And yeah, whatever you ask in ERP wont have much code in it unless you are asking for PL/SQl queries for manipulating data.

Comment: @prince Where it fits? I don't know. Not every question as a platform suited for it.

Comment: @PeterMortensen It wasn't because of the closure that this post was on the front page - there was a spam answer. Closing does *not* bump posts.